# Shouldn't all the NAND gates in your computer activate at the same time?

Tags: memory, ram, nand

When you plug in your computer, shouldn't all the NAND gates activate (because the output turns on when the both inputs are off) at the same time, causing chaos?

For example: RAM is made of memory circuits, which are made entirely of NAND gates, so wouldn't it go insane, storing random values at startup?

Edit: I didn't realize memory circuits are the only parts in the computer made with actual NAND gates, oops.

Comment: What in the world do you mean only NAND gate? You would be pretty restricted with that kind of circuitry. I'm not too familiar with computer hardware and I understand their main storage method is through NAND Gates but the control circuit controlling the memory uses other types of circuitry, not just NAND gates.

Comment: This question is predicated on a lot of bad assumptions.

Comment: RAM is not made of NAND gates as far as I know. I don't see any NAND gates [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/DRAM_Cell_Structure_%28Model_of_Single_Circuit_Cell%29.PNG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you plug in your computer, shouldn't all the NAND gates activate (because the output turns on when the both inputs are off) at the same time, causing chaos?

Well what if they did? The CPU won't do anything until the power-up reset (usually a resistor-capacitor time delay) lets go of the reset pin. This time delay should be designed to be long enough to let the supply voltage stabilise.

Next the CPU bootloader will operate from some non-volatile memory and start to load the OS which also will be stored in EEPROM or HD or similar and load that into RAM overwriting any random data in there. The OS can now continue to run from the (non-chaotic) RAM.

No chaos. All in order.

Comment: So you're saying that it will be random which gates activate when, but their electricity will stop moving by the time the reset happens, correct?

Comment: (1) Not really. Logic outputs won't switch either way until the voltage reaches a couple of volts. The transistors won't work below this level. At this stage inputs which are pulled high or low by external inputs or pull-up resistors will start to set the outputs of the devices they are connected to and so on. (2) "_their electricity will stop moving_" is sort of technobabble. No electricity moves until current _starts_ flowing. (3) "_by the time the reset happens_". The reset is happening all the time from power-up until it _stops_ happening - i.e., when the reset time has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, a NAND gate "turns on" (drives its output low) whenever both inputs are active (high).

And since some of the gates are driven by other gates, it is possible to keep them from all activating at once.

But yes, RAM generally has "random" values in it at power-up. That's why computers go through a careful "bootstrap" sequence, in which successively larger parts of the machine are initialized to proper values until the entire machine is ready for operation. It generally begins with a single bit, called the "reset" signal, which is set up to make a transition from low to high after the power supplies have stabilized. Everything else ensues from there.

Comment: I understand the third part, I just don't get the first two. So what do you mean by it "turns on" whenever both inputs are active? And the second part, do you mean that it is held back by the enabler in the register?

Comment: The first part is just a correction to your vague description of how a NAND gate works. The second part alludes to the fact that if one NAND gate is activated (low), the input to the NAND gate that it drives will be inactive, forcing the second gate's output high (inactive).

Answer (score 0):

Which came first, the chicken or the egg?  A gate can't turn on until IT has power. So a NAND gate not only can't turn on during power-up because it doesn't have power itself (yet), but ALSO because all the upstream logic that ultimately feeds it is ALSO going through power-up.

Keep in mind that in the Real World, there is a THIRD state. Certainly there is low=0 and high=1, but there is also THIRD state of "unknown" or "undetermined" or "don't care", or "garbage".

Some critical parts (like the read/write heads on a mechanical disk) are DESIGNED so that they CANNOT activate until the power sequence has completed. That prevents garbage from being written on your hard drive during power-up (or power-down, for that matter).  Everything else: the state of the billions of transistors in the CPU; the gigabytes of RAM, etc. are ASSUMED to be UNKNOWN or GARBAGE when the computer boots up.

There is a hard-wired pin/process in the CPU called "Reset" which forces all the critical logic in the CPU to a known, startup condition. The computer holds off on the Reset until all the power supply bus voltages have stabilized. Then hard-wired circuits read the boot code out of EPROM into the CPU cache, and part of the boot-up process is to either clear out or "mark" as "unknown" all the blocks of memory in the RAM.

The display memory also has random bits in it, so special circuits blank the display output until the CPU has had a chance to clear it out. And, special hardware in the I/O ports hold them "inert" during power-up so that they don't accidentally trigger the missile to fire or the burglar alarm to sound.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the wording of the question suggests that you think the "active" state of a gate consumes more power than the opposite state.  But they don't work that way.  Whether a gate is high or low, it is prepared to source or sink a certain amount of current in order to enforce that (high or low) state.  What determines that current is what is connected to that output.  And in a logic system such as you envision, almost all outputs are connected to other inputs.  Inputs draw very little current, so even if things happen as you say, there's not much effect on power draw.

As for "chaos", something like that does exist until the power-on reset circuits do their job.  Following a proper reset, order is restored.